# linq - left outer join with where returning list of nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Here is the full query(without the `where`), that works:

```
public List<TipoResiduo> filtro(TipoResiduo objent)
    {
        using (var db = new DBEntities())
        {
            var consulta = (from a in db.tb006_tipo_residuo
                            join cr in db.tb016_classe_residuo on a.fk_id_classe_residuo equals cr.id into trcr
                            from classeresiduo in trcr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join gr in db.tb017_grupo_residuo on a.fk_id_grupo_residuo equals gr.id into trgr
                            from gruporesiduo in trgr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join tfg in db.tb008_tipo_fonte_geradora on a.fk_id_tipo_fonte_geradora equals tfg.id into trtfg
                            from tipofontegeradora in trtfg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join civig in db.tb051_categoria_ivig on a.fk_id_categoria_ivig equals civig.id into trci
                            from categoriaivig in trci.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join icap in db.tb048_ibama_capitulo on a.fk_id_ibama_capitulo equals icap.id into tric
                            from ibamacapitulo in tric.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join isubcap in db.tb049_ibama_subcapitulo on a.fk_id_ibama_subcapitulo equals isubcap.id into tris
                            from ibamasubcapitulo in tris.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join ires in db.tb050_ibama_residuo on a.fk_id_ibama_residuo equals ires.id into trir
                            from ibamaresiduo in trir.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            //where a.fk_id_classe_residuo == objent.fk_id_classe_residuo
                            select new TipoResiduo()
                            {
                                id = a.id,
                                no_tipo_residuo = a.no_tipo_residuo,
                                dt_cadastro = a.dt_cadastro,
                                fk_id_classe_residuo = a.fk_id_classe_residuo,
                                fk_id_grupo_residuo = a.fk_id_grupo_residuo,
                                nu_densidade = a.nu_densidade,
                                fk_id_tipo_fonte_geradora = a.fk_id_tipo_fonte_geradora,
                                fk_id_categoria_ivig = a.fk_id_categoria_ivig,
                                fk_id_ibama_capitulo = a.fk_id_ibama_capitulo,
                                fk_id_ibama_subcapitulo = a.fk_id_ibama_subcapitulo,
                                fk_id_ibama_residuo = a.fk_id_ibama_residuo,
                                no_classe_residuo = classeresiduo == null ? String.Empty : classeresiduo.no_classe_residuo,
                                no_grupo_residuo = gruporesiduo == null ? String.Empty : gruporesiduo.no_grupo_residuo,
                                no_tipo_fonte_geradora = tipofontegeradora == null ? String.Empty : tipofontegeradora.no_tipo_fonte_geradora,
                                no_categoria_ivig = categoriaivig == null ? String.Empty : categoriaivig.no_categoria_ivig,
                                no_ibama_capitulo = ibamacapitulo == null ? String.Empty : ibamacapitulo.de_ibama_capitulo,
                                no_ibama_subcapitulo = ibamasubcapitulo == null ? String.Empty : ibamasubcapitulo.de_ibama_subcapitulo,
                                no_ibama_residuo = ibamaresiduo == null ? String.Empty : ibamaresiduo.de_ibama_residuo
                                });
            return consulta.OrderBy(a => a.no_tipo_residuo).ToList();
        }
}
```

My object `TipoResiduo` has some virtual fields just for convenience and can have some null fields.

And when I try to filter with the `where`(removing the `//`) the query shows nothing. The `ObjEnt` of the function has some fields previously populated, and when the field is null, I want to show all.

I tried this too, and nothing:

```
where a.fk_id_classe_residuo == 
(objent.fk_id_classe_residuo == null 
? 0 : objent.fk_id_classe_residuo)
```

I'm new at this, what should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You have no left outer join so I don't understand the title

If objent.fk_id_classe_residuo is null this will find a.fk_id_classe_residuo = 0 - not all

```
where a.fk_id_classe_residuo ==  (objent.fk_id_classe_residuo == null  ? 0 : objent.fk_id_classe_residuo)
```

try this

```
where objent.fk_id_classe_residuo == null 
   or a.fk_id_classe_residuo == objent.fk_id_classe_residuo
```

Comment: I think you tried to say: `where a.fk_id_classe_residuo == null || a.fk_id_classe_residuo == objent.fk_id_classe_residuo`
But I already fixed it, thx anyway. :)

Comment: I can only answer the stated question.  "The ObjEnt of the function has some fields previously populated, and when the field is null, I want to show all."  Field is object.  id_classe_residuo == null would not show all - it shows values of null.

Answer (score -1):

After hitting my head into the wall, I found the answer:

```
where objent.fk_id_classe_residuo == 0 ? true : classeresiduo.id == null
&& classeresiduo.id == null ? false : a.fk_id_classe_residuo == objent.fk_id_classe_residuo
```

The problem is this `objent.fk_id_classe_residuo` comes from a dropdownlist, and I set this `fk_id` as 0 when no option is given. Well, would be very difficult to someone help me with this. :|

But I thank Blam for his attention. ;)

Comment: classeresiduo.id == null && classeresiduo.id == null ? false does nothing.  Any comparison to null returns false.

Comment: You are right, looking at it again seems strange, but somehow this works.
This works too, but makes more sense(I think): `where objent.fk_id_classe_residuo == 0 ? true : objent.fk_id_classe_residuo == null
&& objent.fk_id_classe_residuo == null ? false : a.fk_id_classe_residuo == objent.fk_id_classe_residuo`

Comment: Really explicitly checking for null and returning false when any comparison to null returns false anyway makes more sense?